# HTTP ERROR (404) with uploadify and custom uploader for asp net [ASP NET MVC 4]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, uploadify

I need to implement uploadify on my asp net mvc 4 application.

I have replaced the uploadify.php with this simple class just for test purpose:

```
public class uploadify : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpPostedFile oFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];

        oFile.SaveAs("C:\\" + oFile.FileName);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

And the config is like that:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'swf': '../../Components/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader': '../../Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.cs',
    'auto': false,
    'buttonText': 'Selecionar',
    'debug': true
});
```

I am getting a `HTTP ERROR (404)`
The path for the uploadify.cs is correct so I don´t see why this resource is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing the site in MVC 4, why not just use a controller instead of an IHttpHandler?

Example of '[How do I get jQuery's Uploadify plugin to work with ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002680/how-do-i-get-jquerys-uploadify-plugin-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc)'

Comment: Thanks... in 4 minutes I ll give you an extra reputation.. ;o)